# Join two timeseries dataframes to get the most recent right entry for each left entry in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two Sparks dataframes:

`df1` with one entry per `id` and `date`:

```
|date       |id   |
+-----------+-----+
|2021-11-15 |    1|
|2021-11-14 |    1|
|2021-11-15 |    2|
|2021-11-14 |    2|
|2021-11-15 |    3|
|2021-11-14 |    3|
```

`df2` with multiple log entries:

```
|date       |id   |
+-----------+-----+
|2021-11-13 |    1|
|2021-11-13 |    1|
|2021-11-13 |    3|
|2021-11-14 |    1|
|2021-11-14 |    1|
|2021-11-14 |    1|
|2021-11-14 |    1|
|2021-11-15 |    1|
|2021-11-15 |    1|
```

how can I join these dfs, so that I get the most recent possible entry (date(df2) should be <= date) per `id` and `date` of `df2`?

```
|date       |id    |   date(df2)| 
+-----------+------+------------+
|2021-11-15 |    1 | 2021-11-15 |
|2021-11-14 |    1 | 2021-11-14 |
|2021-11-15 |    2 |       null |
|2021-11-14 |    2 |       null |
|2021-11-15 |    3 | 2021-11-13 |
|2021-11-14 |    3 | 2021-11-13 |
```

THX
Into Numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join then group by `df1.id` and `df2.date` and use conditional aggregation to get max `df2.date <= df1.date`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


result_df = df1.join(
    df2.withColumnRenamed("date", "df2_date"),
    ["id"],
    "left"
).groupBy("id", "date").agg(
    F.max(
        F.when(F.col("df2_date") <= F.col("date"), F.col("df2_date"))
    ).alias("df2_date")
)

result_df.show()
#+---+----------+----------+
#| id|      date|  df2_date|
#+---+----------+----------+
#|  1|2021-11-14|2021-11-14|
#|  1|2021-11-15|2021-11-15|
#|  2|2021-11-14|      null|
#|  2|2021-11-15|      null|
#|  3|2021-11-14|2021-11-13|
#|  3|2021-11-15|2021-11-13|
#+---+----------+----------+
```